# Using an ArrayList to create a dynamic 2d array of integers

Tags: java, arraylist, radix-sort

So I'm trying to implement this pseudo-code for the radix sort and don't understand how to create a 2D ArrayList that this code is implying must be created. I've looked at other posts on creating a 2D ArrayList but don't understand how to properly implement it in this situation. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
RadixSort(array, arraySize) {

   buckets = create array of 10 buckets

   // Find the max length, in number of digits

   maxDigits = RadixGetMaxLength(array, arraySize)

   // Start with the least significant digit

   pow10 = 1

   for (digitIndex = 0; digitIndex < maxDigits; digitIndex++) {

  for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {

     bucketIndex = abs(array[i] / pow10) % 10

     Append array[i] to buckets[bucketIndex]
  }

  arrayIndex = 0

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

     for (j = 0; j < buckets[i].size(); j++)

        array[arrayIndex++] = buckets[i][j]

  }

  pow10 = 10 * pow10

  Clear all buckets

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int buckets[][] = new int[10][arraySize]; // create array of 10 buckets
```